# Can't define a correct array in this code

Tags: javascript

I need help to organize an array in a function node in node-red.

When data is valid (flag = A) ... running fine
When data is invalid (flag = else) ... Wrong split. The additional array wifiAccessPoints (answer.wifiAccessPoints) can't be split like it should be, as: ssid, macAddress, signalStrength

Below, there are only 4 wifiAccessPoints, but it can be really more.

```
// when flag = A
```

//IWAP01080524A2232.9806N11404.9355E000.1061830323.8706000908000102,460,0,9520,3671#

```
// when flag = else
```

//IWAP01080524V0000.0000N00000.0000E000.1061830323.8706000908000102,460,0,9520,3671,Home|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97&Home1|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97&Home2|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97&Home3|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97#

```
let answer = {}
let elements = msg.payload.replace('#','').split(",")                                                           // this gives an array containing the bits
// elements[0] is the long string starting IWAP01
answer.command = elements[0].substr(0,6)
let dateStr = elements[0].substr(6,6)                                                                           // eg "190215" 15th Feb 2019
answer.date = new Date(Number(dateStr.substr(0,2))+2000, Number(dateStr.substr(2,2))-1, dateStr.substr(4,2))    // 080524 - date
answer.valid = (elements[0].substr(12,1) === "A")                                                               // true or false - A or V
if (answer.valid) {
    let degreesN = Number(elements[0].substr(13,2))
    let minutesN = Number(elements[0].substr(15,7))
    let ns = elements[0].substr(22,1)                                                                           // N or S
    let degreesE = Number(elements[0].substr(23,3))
    let minutesE = Number(elements[0].substr(26,7))
    let ew = elements[0].substr(33,1)                                                                           // E or W
    node.warn(`${degreesN}  ${minutesN}  ${ns}  ${degreesE}  ${minutesE} ${ew}`)
    answer.latitude = degreesN + minutesN/60                                                                    // 2232.9806N
    if (ns === "S") answer.latitude = -answer.latitude
    answer.longitude = degreesE + minutesE/60
    if (ew === "W") answer.longitude = -answer.longitude                                                        // 11404.9355E
} else {
    answer.latitude = 0
    answer.longitude = 0
}

answer.speedMoving = elements[0].substr(34,5)                                                                   // 000.1
answer.angleDirection = elements[0].substr(45,6)                                                                // 323.87
answer.GSMsignal = elements[0].substr(51,3)                                                                     // 060
answer.satellites = elements[0].substr(54,3)                                                                    // 009
answer.batteryLevel = elements[0].substr(57,3)                                                                  // 080
// LBS datas
answer.mobileCountryCode = elements[1]                                                                          // 460
answer.mobileNetworkCode = elements[2]                                                                          // 0
answer.locationAreaCode = elements[3]                                                                           // 9520       
answer.cellId = elements[4]                                                                                     // 3671
// WIFI bases only with flag = else
//
// answer.wifiAccessPoints = elements[5]
//
answer.wifiAccessPoints = []
if (answer.valid === "else") {
    i = elements[4]+1                 // move on to wifi bases
    let wifiAccessPointsStrings = elements[5].split("&")
    let j;
    for (j=0; j<wifiAccessPointsStrings.length; j++) {
        let baseElements = wifiAccessPointsStrings[j].split("|")
        answer.wifiAccessPoints.push({ssid: baseElements[0], macAddress: baseElements[1], signalStrength: baseElements[2]})  // Home|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97&Home1|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97&Home2|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97&Home3|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97
    }
}

msg.payload = answer
return msg
```

Comment: please add a function header and a call with some values and the expected result. have considered to use a regular expression to get the parts of the string, instead of using `substr`?

Comment: Hi Nina, I'm not a dev at all... I understand around 8% of this code which was created by someone else who is not available for 1 month... If you start to speak in technical terms, I'm lost... If it is necessary to use regular expression here... which I understand as simplified code... to solve my actual problem, I can try... but don't know how :) But if this is not essential to solve this issue, it is probably better to dissociate the steps.. Please, tell me...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, the main problem was the check of an ungiven value of `'else'` vs `false`, in this line

```
answer.valid = elements[0].substr(12, 1) === "A"
```

for a later check in this line,

```
if (answer.valid === "else") { // wrong, answer.valid contains a boolean
```

replaced by

```
if (!answer.valid) {
```

and by omitting a not used assignment to a not declared value,

```
i = elements[4] + 1 // ns: i never used
```

it should run.

Please test the result and give a feedback.

```js
function functionWithoutAnInterestingName(msg) {
    let answer = {}
    let elements = msg.payload.replace('#', '').split(",")                                                           // this gives an array containing the bits
    // elements[0] is the long string starting IWAP01
    answer.command = elements[0].substr(0, 6)
    let dateStr = elements[0].substr(6, 6)                                                                           // eg "190215" 15th Feb 2019
    answer.date = new Date(Number(dateStr.substr(0, 2)) + 2000, Number(dateStr.substr(2, 2)) - 1, dateStr.substr(4, 2))    // 080524 - date
    answer.valid = elements[0].substr(12, 1) === "A"                                                               // true or false - A or V
    if (answer.valid) {
        let degreesN = Number(elements[0].substr(13, 2))
        let minutesN = Number(elements[0].substr(15, 7))
        let ns = elements[0].substr(22, 1)                                                                           // N or S
        let degreesE = Number(elements[0].substr(23, 3))
        let minutesE = Number(elements[0].substr(26, 7))
        let ew = elements[0].substr(33, 1)                                                                           // E or W
        // ns: node does not exist!
        // node.warn(`${degreesN}  ${minutesN}  ${ns}  ${degreesE}  ${minutesE} ${ew}`)
        console.log(`${degreesN}  ${minutesN}  ${ns}  ${degreesE}  ${minutesE} ${ew}`)
        answer.latitude = degreesN + minutesN / 60                                                                    // 2232.9806N
        if (ns === "S") answer.latitude = -answer.latitude
        answer.longitude = degreesE + minutesE / 60
        if (ew === "W") answer.longitude = -answer.longitude                                                        // 11404.9355E
    } else {
        answer.latitude = 0
        answer.longitude = 0
    }

    answer.speedMoving = elements[0].substr(34, 5)                                                                   // 000.1
    answer.angleDirection = elements[0].substr(45, 6)                                                                // 323.87
    answer.GSMsignal = elements[0].substr(51, 3)                                                                     // 060
    answer.satellites = elements[0].substr(54, 3)                                                                    // 009
    answer.batteryLevel = elements[0].substr(57, 3)                                                                  // 080
    // LBS datas
    answer.mobileCountryCode = elements[1]                                                                          // 460
    answer.mobileNetworkCode = elements[2]                                                                          // 0
    answer.locationAreaCode = elements[3]                                                                           // 9520
    answer.cellId = elements[4]                                                                                     // 3671
    // WIFI bases only with flag = else
    //
    // answer.wifiAccessPoints = elements[5]
    //
    answer.wifiAccessPoints = []
    if (!answer.valid) {
        //i = elements[4] + 1       // ns: i never used          // move on to wifi bases
        let wifiAccessPointsStrings = elements[5].split("&")
        let j;
        for (j = 0; j < wifiAccessPointsStrings.length; j++) {
            let baseElements = wifiAccessPointsStrings[j].split("|")
            answer.wifiAccessPoints.push({ ssid: baseElements[0], macAddress: baseElements[1], signalStrength: baseElements[2] })  // Home|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97&Home1|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97&Home2|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97&Home3|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97
        }
    }

    msg.payload = answer
    return msg
}

var a = 'IWAP01080524A2232.9806N11404.9355E000.1061830323.8706000908000102,460,0,9520,3671#',
    b = 'IWAP01080524V0000.0000N00000.0000E000.1061830323.8706000908000102,460,0,9520,3671,Home|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97&Home1|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97&Home2|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97&Home3|74-DE-2B-44-88-8C|97#';

console.log(functionWithoutAnInterestingName({ payload: a }));
console.log(functionWithoutAnInterestingName({ payload: b }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nina, I still have the biggest part of my project to solve... and this is now totally outside of my small skills. You understood I'm collecting datas from a device to get a tracking postion... But on this device, the  GPS is rarely used cause of electric consumption... So it is using a LBS and WIFI locating system... The watch is sending all infos to my server ... that I have to send to a locating free service (Mozilla) in an API (only a few of what I'm receiving) in a json body... it should reply the server : longitude and latitude position. DO YOU ACCEPT TO HELP ME FOR THAT IF YOU CAN ?

Comment: sorry, i have no idea of wifi stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I only explain you how it is working... The purpose is just to write the js script to pick up the datas from what I receive from the device and send them with a scripted API I already have...

Comment: right, but here in comments, it's not the right place to ask or answer a complex problem. maybe you could fit the problem into a question.